# scala reflection error java

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I'm trying to use scala.reflect to get the class attributes and to write them XML. 
However I'm getting a strange error

```
 def toXml(): xml.Elem = {
<node>{
  for(field: scala.reflect.Field <- getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    val tmpString = "<" + field.name + ">" + this.getClass().getMethods.find(_.getName == field.name).get.invoke(this) + "</" + field.name + ">"
    print(tmpString)
  }
 }</node>
}
```

The error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.reflect.Field => Unit
required: java.lang.reflect.Field => ?
for(field: scala.reflect.Field <- getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
```

So even if I explicitly use scala.reflect.Field, it still is viewed as java.lang.reflect.Field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getClass().getDeclaredFields()` returns `java.lang.reflect.Field` objects. Unless you find a way to convert between these two classes, you cannot declare them as `scala.reflect.Field` and expect them to work.

EDIT: fix for your code:

```
for(field: java.lang.reflect.Field <- getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
```

Comment: is there any way to get the list of class fields in scala?

Comment: @user485659, see the edit. Keep in mind that in a lot of cases, you don't even need to declare the type, as it will be inferred.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm facing another issue here now, I'm trying to get the type of an attribute that refers to a custom class, I just get that it's of type Object

My code: 
    <edge>{
      for(field: java.lang.reflect.Field <- getClass().getDeclaredFields())
       yield <field name={field.getName()} tpe={field.getType().toString()}>{ this.getClass().getMethods.find(_.getName == field.getName()).get.invoke(this) }</field>
    }</edge>